# Magento 2.2.3 How to check if attribute exist in current product?

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, frontend, magento2.2.3

I want to check if attribute exist in current product by attribute code.

**For Ex:** attribute code if **color** and this attribute is assign to current product. but if i pass something else like **abcde** and this attribute doesn't exist in current product.

So how can i filter is current value is not attribute?

Comment: I think you can try this `$product->hasData('custom_attribute')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution in below way as per my specific requirement.

```
public function getAttributeValue($product, $code){

    $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');
    if ($attribute)
    {
        if (in_array(
            $product->getResource()->getAttribute($code)->getFrontendInput(),
            ['select', 'text']
        )) {
            $value = $product->getAttributeText($code);
        } else {
            $value = $product->getData($code);
        }
    } else {
        $value = '';
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Where in above `$product` is current product and `$code` is attribute code.

Answer (score 2):

try this

`$product->hasData('custom_attribute')` OR `$product->hasCustomAttribute()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope this is what looking for

```
if ($product->getCustomAttributes()) {
        $attribute_value = $product->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code') ?  $product->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')->getValue() : '';
        return $attribute_value;
}
```

Try it and do let me know.
Peace :)

Comment: Tnxs for answer. but it is giving me error `Array to string conversion`  any way i found other solution.
+1 for your efforts. :)

Comment: The above example return array which you might have tried echo, the errors denotes that. Check it or if error persist update the answer because it will be useful for other who visit here.

Comment: But why attribute return value is an array? how can i get in string?

Comment: Updated, now check and let me know